# Convert the SQL Query in to Linq Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I am new to EF Core Framework and trying to learn it. I have tried executing a SQL Query and got the response from the DB but now trying to convert the below SQL query in to Linq query to use it with the EF Core. My SQL Query is like below

```
public static string shipQuery = @"SELECT distinct newid() as  Id
                  ,[prj_number]
                  ,[ship_Date]
                  ,[delivery]
                  ,,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),  [delDate], 110) as delDate
                  ,[po]
                  ,[so]      
                  ,SUM([qty_so]) as total_qty
                  FROM [sDev].[dbo].[PrjDetails] 
                  where [Rep_Prj] = @rep and [so_status] not in ('Canceled','Voided lines') 
                  group by Id,[prj_number],[ship_Date],[delivery],delDate,[po],[so]
                  ORDER BY ship_Date DESC";
```

I have used this SQL Query in to my EF Core Framework to get the data like

```
_context.shipByRepo.FromSql<shipByRepo>(shipQueries.shipQuery, rep).ToList();
```

This works as expected. To improvise the framework I am trying to convert the query in to Linq query. 
As intial try I just filtered by the `rep`

```
   _context.shipByRepo.Where(w => w.Reporting_Project == rep).ToList();
```

And this works, but I am not sure how can I do the above like like doing the date conversion& sum along with the Group by and Orderby

Earlier with the SQL Query I had the model as

```
  public class shipByRepo : IshipByRepo
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string prj_number { get; set; }
    public string ship_Date { get; set; }
    public string delivery { get; set; }
    public string delDate { get; set; }
    public string po { get; set; }
    public string so { get; set; }
    public decimal? total_qty { get; set; }
  }
```

But with the Linq query I changed I modified the Model class without including the total quantity/Converted date fiels

```
  public class shipByRepo : IshipByRepo
  {
    public string prj_number { get; set; }
    public string ship_Date { get; set; }
    public string delivery { get; set; }
    public DateTime? delDate { get; set; }
    public string po { get; set; }
    public string so { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Can you add your entity model?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Updated the Model class

Comment: What is the value of the gui here?   I don't understand how it can have any value since it is not stored in the data base is is just generated as the values are selected.

Comment: also, since you are generating a unique GUID on every row, DISTINCT does nothing.

Comment: @Hogan I need a unique Id on each record for the Entity frmaework to work

Comment: @trx -- this is the wrong way to solve that problem.  You should add a unique id to the table

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might get you started?

Comment: @Hogan I have unique ID on the table but It doesnt help me with the grouping by

Comment: Well, where did `qty_so` go?

Comment: A unique ID you create as a query result will not help EF to associate rows back to a table. What do you expect EF to do with the unique ID? I don't think your SQL Query makes sense either, having both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` `Id`, which is presumably unique per answer row?

Answer (score 0):

I think below code may help you

```cs
    _context.shipByRepo
    .Where(x => x.Rep_Prj == rep && !x.so_status.Contains("Canceled") 
    && !x.so_status.Contains("Voided lines"))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ship_Date).Distinct().ToList();
```

if you want to select number of fields that use `.Select(x=> new { x.propertyName, x.anotherOne })`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OrderBy`(`OrderByDescending`) and `GroupBy` like below:

```
_context.shipByRepo.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ship_Date)
                   .GroupBy(x=>new { x.prj_number,x.ship_Date,x.delivery,x.so,x.po,x.delDate})
                   .ToList();
```